# WordPress: ЧПУ ссылки при наведении

Tags: wordpress, чпу

У меня на сайте настроены ЧПУ ссылки и при переходе из категории в запись получаю в адресной строке адрес вида mysite/katalog/item, как и нужно. Однако, если я навожусь на заголовок записи в категории, всплывающее окно браузера показывает ссылку вида mysite/?p=7555. Как в этом окошке тоже настроить ЧПУ ссылки?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Как правильно задать вопрос по WordPress? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Comment: Скрипт, который выводит этот блок, так формирует адрес. Смотрите код. Без него только гадать.